# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1. I updated Android SDK and Android tools. Also I searched and tried various solution other people tried, but none of them worked.

What should I do?

**Top Level build gradle**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'    
  }      
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
  }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app build gradle file**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
   defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.reminder"
     minSdkVersion 14
     targetSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"        }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }     
  }
 }
 dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
 }
```

gradle sync screenshot
[image: gradle sync]

Comment: It should be able to find those in the `google()` repository. Is your development machine able to access [the Web page for that repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html)?

Comment: I'm from Iran and unfortunately  the link is not accessible for us. but I'm using a proxy and updated android SDK with that proxy too.  
 I can't load the website without a proxy. @CommonsWare

Comment: Maybe you need to do something to teach Gradle about the proxy. I have not dealt with that issue, but surely others have.

Comment: I already defined the proxy host and port for gradle @CommonsWare

Comment: i have same problen in linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following lines in gradle.properties file inside your project:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
```

And also in the following file:

```
Windows: C:\Users\[username]\.gradle\gradle.properties
Linux: /home/[username]/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

And finally sync your project again.

Note: The credits goes to the author of the post in [this link](https://sokanacademy.com/forum/7819/%D9%85%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88--%D9%88-%DA%A9%D9%85%DA%A9-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%B9-%D8%AE%D8%B7%D8%A7-%D9%87%D8%A7).